# JSP Error When Attempting to Display Entire Contents of Database in Table

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

Basically I'm trying to loop through my database and display all of the information inside. I understand the concept that but my implementation is clearly wrong as Tomcat keeps giving me the the following error:

```
Root cause:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I know the problem is with my while loop but my knowledge is limited and I cannot spot the changes I need to make. Please feel free to change the code.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://addr.to.db:3306/dbname";
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
%>

<html>

<head>
<title>JSP Server Response</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>JSP Server Response:</h1>

<!--Get information from HTML form for manipulation-->

<%
    String songName = request.getParameter("newSongName");
String artistName = request.getParameter("newArtistName");
String password = request.getParameter("pass");
String radioResults = request.getParameter("dbIO");
%>

<%

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "userName", "password");
statement = connection.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT * FROM song_info;";
rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

//Add or Delete Information from DB

if(radioResults.equalsIgnoreCase("insert"))
{
    statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO song_info (songTitle, artistName) VALUES                     ('"+artistName+"','"+songName+"')");
}
else if(radioResults.equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))
{
statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM song_info WHERE artistName='"+songName+"'");
}
%>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Song Name</th><th>Artist Name</th>
</tr>

<% while(rs.next()){ %>
<tr>
<td align=center> <%= rs.getString("songTitle")%></td>
<td align=center> <%= rs.getString("artistName")%></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>

<%
rs.close();
statement.close();
connection.close();
%>

Information Submitted to Server:

Artist Name: <%=songName%> <br />
Song Name: <%=artistName%> <br />
Password: <%=password%><br />
Radio Button Selection: <%=radioResults%><br /><br />

Password Correct: 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same `Statement` object to execute multiple queries. If you re-use the `Statement`, then any resources like `ResultSet` from a previous execution are closed.

The solution is either to re-order the query (like you did in your own answer), or to use separate `Statement` objects for the query and the updates.

Also your current code exposes you to SQL injection. Please use `PreparedStatement` with parametrized queries. This will protect you from most - if not all - SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to come up with a makeshift solution that concatenates all the lines of the DB into one long string and then displays the string to the browser:

```
<%

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "userName", "dbPass");
statement = connection.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT songTitle, artistName FROM song_info";
rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

String db_contentsORIGINAL = "";

while (rs.next()) {
    String artName = rs.getString("artistName");
    String sName = rs.getString("songTitle");

    String db_entry = "<b>Artist:</b> " + artName + " | " + "<b>Song Title:         </b>" + sName + "<br />";

        db_contentsORIGINAL += db_entry;
}

//Add or Delete Information from DB

if(radioResults.equalsIgnoreCase("insert"))
{
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO song_info (songTitle, artistName) VALUES         ('"+artistName+"','"+songName+"')");
}
else if(radioResults.equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))
{
statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM song_info WHERE artistName='"+songName+"'");
}

%>
```